# How to take a list of dates in moment.js weekday calculation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

I'm using Moment.js to calculate the different between 2 given dates.
Specially my task is to calculate weekdays of the given date range and not calculate and weekend and also special given date like holidays.

[Moment.JS](https://momentjs.com/)

I found this nice library to do the calculation easily which is integrated with Moment.js : [Weekday Calc with Moment Library](https://github.com/andruhon/moment-weekday-calc)

This is the code I used to get specific dates between a given date range.

```
moment().weekdayCalc({  
  rangeStart: '1 Apr 2015',  
  rangeEnd: '31 Mar 2016',  
  weekdays: [1,2,3,4,5],  
  exclusions: ['6 Apr 2015','7 Apr 2015'],
  inclusions: ['10 Apr 2015']
})
```

From this code, I get only a numeric output. ( Result is 260 )

Can I get a dates list in a JavaScript array like this :

> ["yyyy-mm-dd" , "yyyy-mm-dd" , "yyyy-mm-dd" , "yyyy-mm-dd" , ..... ]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve what you want with [date-fns](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns) which I'd also encourage you to use instead of Moment for [other reasons](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/275#issuecomment-264934189).
I haven't tested the code below but I'm pretty sure it would be something along these lines.

```
const { eachDay, isWeekend, format } = require('date-fns');
var daysArray = eachDay(
     new Date(2014, 9, 6),
     new Date(2014, 9, 10)
);

var weekdaysArray = daysArray.filter(day => !isWeekend(day));
var formattedWeekdays = weekdaysArray.map(day => format(day, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
```